# Data structure which treats nonadjacent memory buffers as a contiguous buffer

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need a data structure which accepts several nonadjacent buffers and, I, as the user of this class, can see just one big contiguous buffer. Suppose I can add any number of buffers to it, using some API like this:

```
void add_buffer(uint8_t* buffer, size_t buffer_length);
```

and then I can get `n bytes` of it using this function:

```
uint8_t* get_buffer(size_t buffer_size, bool& allocated);
```

Each buffer is nonadjacent with other buffers, but address returned by above function is for a contiguous memory block. If requested buffer size from `get_buffer`, is less than or equals to the first buffer inside the class, just the beginning address of the first buffer will be returned, but if the requested buffer is distributed across several inserted buffers, new memory will be allocated and data from these buffers will be copied to it and the contiguous memory address will be returned.

Now I want to know, Is there any implementation of this data structure or not, furthermore, What is the name of this structure :) Maybe if I knew the name of it, I could find it in my searches.

Comment: Like [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think it's not, :) Did you read the question completely?

Comment: Then no, no such data structure is possible. If the separate smaller buffers are non-adjacent then you can't get a contiguous block from those smaller buffers. Only emulate it like `std::deque` by using your own indexing operator overload.

Comment: And *why* do you want this? What is the use-case? What is the actual problem you want to solve? Perhaps you should ask about that, instead of asking about help with a solution to a (for us) unknown problem?

Comment: First of all, when I see a guy with such a big reputation on stackoverflow, I scare :D Why not possible? As I said you allocate new memory large enough to hold requested buffer and copy from all of smaller buffers to it. I need it for a parser which accepts its input stream from network.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Then you can easily implement it using a `std::deque` for the smaller buffer and then copy the data needed into a `std::vector` when you need the contiguous buffer. Of course, you lose some control over the smaller buffers, and there might be other solutions for keeping smaller buffers (like `boost::asio::buffer` as proposed in an answer).

Comment: Another option is to use a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [boost::asio::buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html). buffer is a single buffer. You can combine several of them into a "single contiguous" buffer with the std containers, e.g. vector<>. You can add a buffer to the collection with push_back.

You can copy content from the buffer collection with

```
vector<const_buffer> buffers = ...;

vector<unsigned char> data(boost::asio::buffer_size(buffers));
boost::asio::buffer_copy(boost::asio::buffer(data), buffers);
```

Btw, if you post a little more info about your problem and what you trying to do, you will probably get better answers faster. Your question sounds a lot like a scatter/gather scenario from networking or disk i/o.

Comment: Thanks. I used your suggestions in my solution.